# Vertical NSLevelIndicator OSX

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, osx-lion

I wonder if there is a way of creating/modifying a NSLevelIndicator object so it can be positioned vertically, i.e. display discrete levels from bottom up, not from left to right, so it can be also used as element of interface-building library in Xcode?

There are lots of examples of such level displays in Apple and non-Apple OSX applications, and quite a few reasons why such an object should exist, yet how to create such an object for some reason (from what I can see in developer forums) seems either not worth asking or a "best kept secret".

Is there a template code which can be modified to into an object of such properties?

I haven't even faintest idea if such an object should really be written from scratch? Mission impossible?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using

```
[NSView setFrameRotation:90];
```

it's sketchy but easier than a custom view

Edit: Alternatively try

```
[levelView setFrameCenterRotation:90];
```

SetFrameRotation:90 rotated it around the bottom left axis for me so it ended up being clipped. This one rotates it around the centre so you should be able to see it. I just made a quick swift playground showcasing it: http://cl.ly/WsL8/Vertical%20LevelIndicatorView.playground.zip

Edit again: If you're still stuck, I made a sample project with a vertical level indicator in objective-c: http://cl.ly/WrdH/levelindicator.zip

Comment: Thanks, but where? How? Which NSView? Obviously not the one belonging to the app's main window per default (resulting in rotation of everything it includes)? I'd sincerely appreciate if someone would be so kind to give few more details.

Comment: for example:  **[_levelIndicator setFrameRotation:90];**  does not work.

Comment: @user3078414 I updated my answer, try setFrameCenterRotation:90

Comment: Thanks for your update. Yet, I'm porting a legacy SGI IRIX app to OSX and prefer staying as conservative as reasonable concerning zippy new IDEs and iOS. Haven't worked neither with swift nor with playground so far. Is this an absolute *must* for fixing the problem? In ordinary Xcode it doesn't seem to work: "Property frameCenterRotation not found on object of type 'NSLevelIndicatorCell".

Comment: @user3078414 ah, you have to call setFrameCenterRotation on NSLevelIndicatorCell's parent, NSLevelIndicator. NSLevelIndicator is the actual view part of it which handles the frame

Comment: Luke, thanks. I got how this works and could implement the analogous code on an older system (10.7.x). Important for me was to understand it has nothing to do with any kind of class-implying-keyword (such as view). Center rotation is a method of **any** NSLevelIndicator object. My problem was that in Xcode and Apple documentation it seems somewhat ambiguous about which is parent, which is child. Although it's basically a hack, it's a nice proof it can work. I do find it somewhat impractical for more serious interface design. Is it possible to perhaps subclass and edit default behavior?

Comment: @user3078414 sorry for the late reply but yes, you can create a subclass of NSLevelIndicator and override its init function. Add [self setFrameCenterRotation:90] in this function before you return self; or something along those lines and you should be good. Also as a general rule of thumb, I've always found that any 'cell' part of an object generally deals with the content, such as NSTextFieldCell holds the actual text, whereas its parent deals with the rendering of the frame and such.

Comment: Luke, thanks. I'll definitely consider this comment as helpful. Yet there are inconsistently documented issues beyond my current time-frame to understand, in the methods of controlling the NSLevelIndicatorCell's behavior, that once used to work as expected, but seemingly got broken since 10.7. So I took the easier way of writing a custom NSOpenGLView subclass, which gives the desired behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Swift 5.5.1 on macOS 11.6

```
myLevelIndicator.frameRotation = 90
```

If you need to reposition the indicator to fit within the view, realize the center of rotation is the origin of the level indicator.

So, to set the rotated level indicator 20px in from the left of the view, compute that for the new frame origin of the level indicator, not forgetting to adjust for the indicators height when it is horizontal because the original height will affect the final position when rotated.

```
myLevelIndicator.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: self.view.frame.minX+20+myLevelIndicator.frame.height, y: myLevelIndicator.frame.minY)
```

Of course, this can be avoided by placing the control in the correct position to allow for rotation within IB if that works for you.  Some may not be using IB and creating these controls programmatically.